# Google BigQuery DML - Error while trying to run basic UPDATE

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to run the following basic UPDATE statement

UPDATE [gcp-or:babynames.names_2014] SET name = "Emma B" WHERE name = "Emma"

However, I am getting the following error:
"Query Failed
Error: 1.1 - 1.76: Unrecognized token UPDATE"

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZbl2.png)

Any suggestions?

Thanks
-Oscar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use standard SQL for DML functionality. To enable standard SQL, see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)

the easiest way is as below

```
#standardSQL  
UPDATE `gcp-or.babynames.names_2014` SET name = "Emma B" WHERE name = "Emma"
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt respons

Comment: For Apache AirFlow users, BigQueryOperator runs with `use_legacy_sql=True` by default. Be sure to set it to False.
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/db4be19b80a65913edb5ab634226cf60ea8bffea/airflow/gcp/operators/bigquery.py#L487